# excel percent complete between start date, end date, and today's date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a simple milestones update with percent complete. I would like to automate this with an excel formula. I can use the start date from the previous row and the end date from the current row and use today's date. So, today is 3/12/20. So I just need to know what percent from start date to today's date with end date in mind. My attempt is below but still have some issues. My formula does not have a start date. Do I need that included? Also, I do not see the percent sign at the end which I want.

```
=IF(TODAY()>=C4,"100%",CONCATENATE(C4-TODAY(),""))
```

Edit. I think I fixed it:

```
=IF(TODAY()>=C4,"100%",MAX((TODAY()-C3)/MAX(C4-C3,1),0))
```

[image]

Comment: I have a little suggestion as to upload the full column and row names!

Answer (score 4):

You want a simple percentage over the total number of days between the milestones:

```
=(TODAY()-C4)/(C5-C4)
```

Make sure the cell is formatted to show Percentage.